# Create a PopUp in Swift using a custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a custom `UIView` and display it as a pop up in my main View using Swift.

My Custom `UIView` code is

```
class DatePopUpView: UIView {
var uiView:UIView?

override init()  {
    super.init()
    self.uiView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DatePopUpView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      }

required override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: frame)

}

}
```

And I am Calling it in my main view as:

```
 @IBAction func date_button_pressed (sender : AnyObject?) {
 var popUpView = DatePopUpView()
 var centre : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y)

    popUpView.center = centre
    popUpView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
  let trans = CGAffineTransformScale(popUpView.transform, 0.01, 0.01)
    popUpView.transform = trans
    self.view .addSubview(popUpView)
    UIView .animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options:     UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

        popUpView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(popUpView.transform, 100.0, 100.0)

        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in

    })

 }
```

But popUp is not Coming. I used breakpoint and noticed that value is getting assigned to my popUpView but still it is not displayed on my main View. Please Help

Please Note: I am using StoryBoard for my mainView and custom View i have made using xib.[image]

Comment: I think you need to More Description about your question

Answer (score 0):

Without additional description on what you are attempting to do, may I suggest something like the code below? Basically, you can use .hidden feature of a view (or any other control) to show/hide the view. You can set the size and positioning of the view to be popped by using the layout editor.

```
        import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var popped = false
        var popupBtnTitle = "Show Popup"
        @IBAction func popupButton(sender: UIButton) {
            popped = !popped
            anotherView.hidden = !popped
            popupBtnTitle = popped  ? "Hide Popup" : "Show Popup"
            popupButtonOutlet.setTitle(popupBtnTitle, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        }
        @IBOutlet weak var popupButtonOutlet: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var anotherView: UIView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            popped = false
            anotherView.hidden = !popped
            popupButtonOutlet.setTitle(popupBtnTitle, forState: UIControlState.Normal)


            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you @syed for suggestion but i tried to drag and drop `UIView` in `Storybord` but was unable to do so. so i created one xib and created a custom view.

Comment: It works fine. Just as a test, create a new project. This will create a ViewController which has a view in it. Now drag a drop down view and place it under the main view. See https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l5h7kk5ntb04hsb/AABgp8c0D9THGUoxlNhrD-uRa?dl=0

Comment: It works fine. Just as a test, create a new project. This will create a ViewController which has a view in it. Now drag a drop down view and place it under the main view. See the project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l5h7kk5ntb04hsb/AABgp8c0D9THGUoxlNhrD-uRa?dl=0